# Why vuejs array shows empty even if it not?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of checkbox which is dynamic.
Whenever I click on the checkbox, it is binded to the data array. The index is provided as the top company name. But the array shows empty when I log the array. But if I iterate through it and log again, it shows the values.
In JS we cannot set the array index directly. Is that the problem?
Code:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {

    topCompanies: [{
            "doc_count": 221,
            "key": "a"
        },
        {
            "doc_count": 175,
            "key": "b"
        },
        {
            "doc_count": 149,
            "key": "c"
        },
        {
            "doc_count": 126,
            "key": "d"
        },
        {
            "doc_count": 116,
            "key": "e"
        },
        {
            "doc_count": 115,
            "key": "f"
        },
        {
            "doc_count": 94,
            "key": "g"
        },
        {
            "doc_count": 89,
            "key": "h"
        },
        {
            "doc_count": 75,
            "key": "h"
        },
        {
            "doc_count": 72,
            "key": "i"
        }
    ],
    collapse1: false,
    checked_company: []
},
methods: {
    getResultsByCompany(result) {
        console.log(this.checked_company)
        temp = []
        for (i in this.checked_company) {
            console.log(i)
        }
    }

}
});
<div id="app">



<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <button class="collapsible" @click="collapse1=!collapse1">Top Companies</button>
      <div v-if="collapse1" class="content" v-bind:style="{'display': 'block'}">
          <div class="list-group" v-for = "(result,index) in topCompanies" :key="result.id">
          <label class="container check-an" :id="index" @change = "getResultsByCompany(result.key)">{{ result.key}}({{result.doc_count }})
              <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked_company[result.key]">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbkx5zdt/

Comment: I checked your jsfiddle, `console.log(this.checked_company)` prints selected value correctly

Comment: No check the new one, I changed to array object,

Comment: Can you try to explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It looks correct on my console https://imgur.com/uK9zCEY

Comment: Yep you can see the result, but the length is zero? And I checked from the vue extension the state doesnot get updated.

Comment: What you want is apparently the number of true values. To get it, you really need to go over the object/array and count the values. The point is, array may have length 5 and contain 5 `false`s, it doesn't look like you want to count them.

Comment: I obviously want to count them and have the key value as well like [{"a":true},{"b":false}].. The problem is I need to define it as object and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `checked_company` as an array, but you treat it as an object `checked_company[result.key]`

If you want to save all checked company key in an array, then your checkbox code should be

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="result.key" v-model="checked_company">
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/9jya1gas/

Comment: So we cant declare object inside a array? btw I got the solution just wanted to know why defining array created the problem.

Comment: You can still declare `checked_company` as an array, but don't try to access it as an object `checked_company[result.key]`. It will lead to expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I see you seem missing several div tags

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">



    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
          <button class="collapsible" @click="collapse1=!collapse1">Top Companies</button>
          <div v-if="collapse1" class="content" v-bind:style="{'display': 'block'}">
              <div class="list-group" v-for = "(result,index) in topCompanies" :key="result.id">
              <label class="container check-an" :id="index" @change = "getResultsByCompany(result.key)">{{ result.key}}({{result.doc_count }})
                  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked_company[result.key]">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
            </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It make vuejs don't know el scope

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure this will be the issue but have you checked that 'this' refers to the correct object? Potentially you could assign a variable to new Vue and reference the object globally. Hope it helps.